# dummy movups generated by gcc

Tags: optimization, gcc, assembly, x86-64, low-level

A little curiosity I found; GCC seems to generate the following code when I have a lot of optimization flags on:

```
00000000004019ae:   test %si,%si
00000000004019b1:   movups %xmm0,%xmm0
00000000004019b4:   je 0x401f40 <main(int, char**)+1904>
```

Question: what purpose does the second instruction serve?  It doesn't look like it /does/ anything; so, is it some optimization to align the program in the instruction cache? Or is it something with out-of-order execution?  (I'm compiling with `-mtune=native` on a Nehalem if that helps :D).

Nothing urgent, of course, just curious.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly `xmm0` contains a result of some calculations, done in integer domain (with integer SSE instruction). And the next instruction using `xmm0` is expected to be in floating point domain (floating point SSE instruction).

Nehalem may perform this next instruction faster if `xmm0` is migrated to floating point domain with instruction like `movaps` or `movups`. And it may be beneficial to perform this migration prior to conditional jump instruction. In this case migration is done only once. If no `movups` instruction used, migration may be done twice (automatically, by the first FP instruction on this register), first time speculatively, on mispredicted branch, and second time - on the correct branch.

It seems, compiler noticed, that it is better to optimize calculation dependency chains, than to optimize for code size and execution resources.

Comment: why would it use movups instead of movaps?

Comment: @PhiS, I don't know. They both are identical with register-only operands.

Comment: Aha, perfect answer! Thanks (and upvoted). I didn't know movaps/movups converted to float, I thought it just did a straight copy, but that makes perfect sense.  And yes, gcc will do that by default unless I specify -Os, I believe.

Comment: I didn't say anything is converted to float. `movups` doesn't change register content in any way. It copies the register bit-to-bit. Also it prepares this register to be processed by floating point execution unit (physically moves register's content to the appropriate place in CPU core).

Comment: ahh ok, so it's something more like mov %eax, %st0, except that there aren't two separate registers in this case. good to know, I figured that was more like it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the hypothesis proposed by Evgeny Kluev, other possibilities (in no particular order) are that (a) it's a compiler optimiser bug, (b) `movups` is inserted to break a dependency or (c) it is inserted for the purpose of code alignment.

Comment: Aha, see, that last one makes sense as well, because IIRC I'm compiling with 16-byte code alignment (no idea why I'm doing that except for experimentation purposes.  Most of my really performance critical code is hand-optimized).

Comment: @vpostman - I don't know which label you're aligning, but the je instruction after the movups seems to be aligned to 4, not 16.